# How do i (ajax) change the content of a div depending on its current content?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I've got a main page with alot of "onclick" elements which use ajax to replace the content of different divs.

Most of these onclick elements are contained within the div that they change, thus they remove themselves and bring up new onclick options.

The problem I'm having is that a few of my onclick elements are meant to change the contents of OTHER divs, however the change they make should be dependent on the category already presented in the div it's trying to change (like A search filter).

So:

Example 1:

```
<div id="1">
HEALTH
<span onclick="ajaxfunction(div1)"> Doctors </span>
<span onclick="ajaxfunction(div1)"> Dentists </span>
<span onclick="ajaxfunction(div1)"> FItness Clubs </span>

<div id="2">
ELECTRONICS
<span onclick="ajaxfunction(div2)"> Video Games </span>
<span onclick="ajaxfunction(div2)"> Computers </span>
<span onclick="ajaxfunction(div2)"> Televisions </span>



<div id="filter">
Select max distance from store

 <form>
 Radio buttons, options 0, 5, 10 miles
 <input type="submit" **onclick="query(div1)**> Refine Results </input>
```

So the important thing I'm trying to do here is that in the bolded js function, "query" I'm going to use mysql select statements to do a subquery of the current div1 results.

My question is, how do i get my js function "query" to know that the div 1 search value is currently "HEALTH"?

Should i make a PHP session variable holding the current value of the div whose value gets assigned to a javascript variable?

Is that possible?

Comment: use a `<select>`. it will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

use a global javascript var to save the div status

```
<script>

var current_stat = 'HEALTH';

function query()
{
    // check the current_Stat
    // do stuff based on the current staff 
    // change the current staff if the div contents chang 
}
</script>
```

Comment: global var is the WORST feature of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<span onclick...` you can also use a normal `<a href`, with the actual url to request as the `href` attribute. You can generate this url from PHP.

Then, (using JQuery, if you like) you can add the onclick event to those links, making them AJAX the url of the clicked link.

If you implement that search page correctly, it will render just the search results when it is an AJAX request, but the full page with the results in it, if it is not an AJAX request. With a proper PHP backend, this should be as simple as a single `if` in your backend code.

The advantages are (in random order):

- You've found your answer (the info you need is already in the url).
- The site will work without javascript too (not only for older browsers, but also for accessibility).
- Screen readers will actually recognise the links, whether they support javascript or not.
- The page is indexed better by search engines (it can follow the links).
- The link behaves like a link, including hover, cursor, etc.
- The link works when someone wants to 'open in new tab/window'